# How to delete quotation marks in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
number    file
  1       "[file1,file2]"
  2       [file1]
  3       "[file3,file4]
```

I want to delete the `"`. This is what I've tried:

```
 data = df.replace([\"], '', regex=True)
```

But, nothing changes in my dataframe. How do I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `df['file'].str.strip('"')`

Comment: @cs95 wouldn't that make the second file row as Null?

Comment: @MohitMotwani I assumed this is a column of strings, but if not then it probably would not work well like `replace`.

Comment: @cs95 actually, `file` is a column of lists

Comment: Either you've mixed lists and strings, or you have a column of strings that look like lists.

Comment: @cs95 I have a column of lists, but when save it into csv file, I got quotation mark in column where the list more than one items

Comment: When you read it back, you read them as strings. print `df['file'].head().tolist()` and take a look.

Comment: I got : `["[file1,file2]",...]` how about quotation mark? is it affect its data type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",delimiter=',')
data = df.replace('"', '', regex=True)
print(data)
```

[image]